# Apache HTTPD close connection or does not redirect request to servlet container

Tags: java, apache, sockets, tomcat, servlets

We have a system includes two parts:

Part I:
A Servlet with "/aaa" url mapping.

Part II:
A simple socket program which connects to our servlet and streams binary data.

The system works fine but, after coming an Apache HTTPD between two parts (our servlet and socket program), the HTTPD prevents data stream.

In the other words, the HTTPD does not redirect request to the Tomcat, I think it waits to receive request completely.

Request header for start out streaming is:

```
POST /aaa HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 2147483647
connection: keep-alive
```

If I replace `Content-Length: 2147483647` header with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, the request will not be redirected to servlet.

Also if I set the `Content-Length` to a smaller value, the request will be redirected to servlet but, the connection will be closed.

The following lines has been come in apache error_log file repeatedly

```
[Wed Sep 07 07:30:34.180585 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2253:tid 140090191890176] [client 162.93.19.34:45769] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: example.com/aaa/
[Wed Sep 07 07:30:34.180700 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 2253:tid 140090191890176] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:12007 (127.0.0.1) failed

[Wed Sep 14 06:25:18.406899 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 27777:tid 140089871005440] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 162.93.19.34:60284] AH01110: error reading response
```

What is your suggestion for an HTTP header to work this correctly?

Comment: Could you post apache revers proxy configuration for the servlet ?

Comment: I can not access to apache configuration, it is a host on the net

Comment: Maybe logs of the apache ?

Comment: I will try to grab it and post here

Comment: I have added apache logs as Edit1 to the question body

Comment: Are apache and servlet in the same machine ? And check the servlet at 127.0.0.1:12007

Comment: Both resides in the same server, as mentioned in the question, with some header, request redirect to the servlet

Comment: Logs say that apache can't connect to the servlet. So maybe servlet is not running...

Comment: You are right, but the servlet answers to some request and running now

Comment: Without apache configuration it is not easy to find what is doing wrong. For me it need that :    SetEnv proxy-sendchunked       1
                                    SetEnv proxy-sendcl            0

Comment: We have another complicated application on this machine, and works fine, I think, there is no problem on HTTPD configuration, I should find a set of correct HTTP request header and replace with existing one, Thank you for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

It is **impossible** to use HTTP to create a **full-duplex** connection between the client and server. There are a number of problems in doing so. The first thing to note is that **HTTP uses a request-response paradigm**, not a full-duplex streaming paradigm.This means that the client sends a request, and when the complete request has been sent then the server sends the response. This is the case even if so-called keep-alive is used, i.e.  multiple requests are sent over the same TCP connection. Because this behavior is fundamental to the protocol most implementations make certain (valid) assumptions which make it difficult to create a full-duplex connection.

## Solutions

The easiest solution is to change your application to use a request-response paradigm. If you are trying to tunnel through an HTTP proxy and for some reason really can't change your paradigm, then here are a couple ideas.

- **Use 2 connections:**

Each connection gives you a simplex stream. Do a simple GET on the first connection and have the server send back a response either without a Content-length header or with a very large Content-length header (or if you're doing HTTP/1.1 you can use the chunked transfer encoding). Also, send the "Pragma: no-cache" and "Cache-Control: no-cache" headers to keep any proxy from caching the response. This response will then give you the server->client simplex stream. Then do a POST with a very large Content-length header on the second connection to get the client->server stream (the response is never received). Note that this won't work with a number of proxies because they will never forward the POST (because they're waiting for the complete data).

- **Use n+1 connections:**

If you are using URLConnection or going through certain proxies then you won't get real client->server stream (because they buffer it all before sending the request). Therefore you must split your client->server stream into blocks and send each block in a separate request. The server->client stream is done as above. Note however that this solution may potentially mean you'll be sending a large number of requests, and if your server or proxy doesn't handle keep-alives then that also means a large number of connections being created. In either case you will still have either write your own (simple) HTTP server, or then write some server side handler using an API native to the server.
[Reference](https://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/fullduplex.html)